# How to create a timetable in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I want to create a student time table having 5 subject, 5 teacher, 5 class, per day 5 hour and 5 day in a week. I have completed everything, but now the issue I am facing is if there is no data inserted for specific one day (suppose for Monday there is no class) and i am inserting data for Tuesday. Then the Tuesday data are showing on Monday.

Here's some images:

Output TimeTable(Here the No Class field's time is 2pm-3pm and day is Thursday. But it is showing in Friday and in 10am-11am)

[image]

My TimeTable database table

[image]

I want to show if there is no row inserted for a day. Then for that day data should be show as 'No Class' in front end time table.
Here I am placing my logic:

```
   <body>
    <?php include 'sidenav.php';?>
    <article>
        <table border="2" style= "background-color: #84ed86; color: #761a9b; margin: 0 auto;" >
              <tr>
                <th><b>TIME</b></th>
                <th><b>Monday</b></th>
                <th><b>Tuesday</b></th>
                <th><b>Wednesday</b></th>
                <th><b>Thursday</b></th>
                <th><b>Friday</b></th>
              </tr>
            <tbody>
                <h1>Class Wise Time Table</h1>
                <?php
                    error_reporting(1);
                    session_start();
                    if ((isset($_SESSION['login'])) && (isset($_REQUEST['cls']))) {
                        $classname = $_REQUEST['cls'];
                        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "finaltask");
                        $sql = "select DISTINCT (time) as time from time_table where classname = "."'$classname'";
                        $rest = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                        while($t = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rest)){
                        $sql = "select * from time_table where classname = "."'$classname'". " AND time = '".$t['time']."'";
                        //print_r($sql);exit;
                        $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
                            //echo '<pre>'; print_r ($row);
                            if(($row['day']=='Monday')&&($row['time']==$t['time'])){
                                echo"<tr> <td>{$row['time']}</td>";
                                if(($row['subject']==' ')&&($row['teacher']== ' ')){
                                    echo "<td>No Class</td>";//die('');
                                }else{
                                    echo  "<td>".$row['subject']."<br>".$row['teacher']."</td>";
                                }
                            }
                            if(($row['day']=='Tuesday')&&($row['time'])){
                                if(($row['subject']=='')&&($row['teacher']=='')){
                                echo "<td>No Class</td>";
                                }else{
                                    echo  "<td>".$row['subject']."<br>".$row['teacher']."</td>";
                                }
                            }
                            if(($row['day']=='Wednesday')&&($row['time'])){
                                if(($row['subject']=='')&&($row['teacher']=='')){
                                echo "<td>No Class</td>";
                                }else{
                                    echo  "<td>".$row['subject']."<br>".$row['teacher']."</td>";
                                }
                            }
                            if(($row['day']=='Thurshday')&&($row['time'])){
                                if(($row['subject']=='')&&($row['teacher']=='')){
                                echo "<td>No Class</td>";
                                }else{
                                    echo  "<td>".$row['subject']."<br>".$row['teacher']."</td>";
                                }
                            }
                            if(($row['day']=='Friday')&&($row['time'])){
                                if(($row['subject']=='')&&($row['teacher']=='')){
                                echo "<td>No Class</td>";
                                }else{
                                    echo  "<td>".$row['subject']."<br>".$row['teacher']."</td></tr>";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                      }
                    }        
                ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: Firstly we are not sure about how you are storing your data into database , second thing is you are using while loop to display the rows from database, so what happens is php will print the data it gets from your database and simply print it. You have to store monday's value with No in your database along with other days if monday is not checked or selected , then database will also give monday in the data and you can use "No" to identify if there is class on that particular day or not. so just store monday even if it's not selected and give it a value `no` or `0` TO identify it as closed

Comment: Thanks Arsh Singh! for responding. Actually I have attached my database table image in this post. In that image you can see how i'm storing data. By the way i am storing everything dynamically. The thing is how to show there is 'NO Class" if there is no data for the day.

Comment: Look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my suggestion for you to go with. You can define a new array, and store the values from while loop organised by week day names and then use create another array with name of week days you want to look through, and with foreach loop you can check if you get any value for the day that is in current loop and then print `No class` for day with no data  and `time table` for the day that have data, look below.

```
<?php
  $days_data = array();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $days_data[$row['day']] == $row;
  }

if($days_data):
    $week_days = array('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday');
    foreach($week_days as $wday){
        if(!empty($days_data[$wday])){
            $row_data = $days_data[$wday]; // $row_data contains all of the data from that specific day time,name,teacher and etc...
            // there is data for this day
        } else {
            // no data for the day currently in loop
        }
    }
endif;
```

Comment: Thanks @Arsh! This logic is working. But i changed a little bit. I am posting my answer here for other beginners. btw thanks alot man. You made my day.

Comment: if my answer did help you , then do accept it by clicking on tick.

Answer (score 1):

## Class Wise Time Table

```
        <table border="2" style= "background-color: #84ed86; color: #761a9b; margin: 0 auto;" >
              <tr>
                <th><b>TIME</b></th>
                <th><b>Monday</b></th>
                <th><b>Tuesday</b></th>
                <th><b>Wednesday</b></th>
                <th><b>Thursday</b></th>
                <th><b>Friday</b></th>
              </tr>
            <tbody>

                <?php
                    error_reporting(1);
                    session_start();
                    if ((isset($_SESSION['login'])) && (isset($_REQUEST['cls']))) {
                        $classname = $_REQUEST['cls'];
                        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "finaltask");
                        $sql = "select DISTINCT (time) as time from time_table where classname = "."'$classname'";
                        $rest = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                        while($t = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rest)){
                        $sql = "select * from time_table where classname = "."'$classname'". " AND time = '".$t['time']."'";
                        //print_r($sql);exit;
                        $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $t['time'] ?></td>
                        <?php
                        $week_days = array('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thurshday','Friday');
                        $classes = array();
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
                            $classes[$row['day']] = $row;
                        }
                        foreach ($week_days as $day) {
                        ?>
                            <?php if (array_key_exists($day, $classes)) { $row = $classes[$day]; ?>
                            <td><?php echo $row['subject'] . '<br />' . $row['teacher'] ?></td>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                            <td>No Class</td>
                            <?php } ?>
                        <?php    
                        }
                        ?>
                        </tr>
                             <?php
                        }     
                ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```